# Avoiding duplicate rows in grid view by c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written following code in order to prevent duplicate rows on the basis of some fields.

I am using template fields in grid view like txtLicenseNumber and lblJurisdiction.

```
    private void AvoidDuplicate()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtoldvalue = grdView.Rows[i].FindControl("txtLicenseNumber") as TextBox;
            string oldvalue = txtoldvalue.Text.ToString();

            Label txtoldvalueJ = grdView.Rows[i].FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label;
            string oldvalueJ = txtoldvalueJ.Text.ToString();

            if (oldvalue != "" || oldvalueJ !="")  
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    TextBox txtnewvalue = grdView.Rows[j].FindControl("txtLicenseNumber") as TextBox;
                    string newvalue = txtnewvalue.Text.ToString();

                    Label txtnewvalueJ = grdView.Rows[j].FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label;
                    string newvalueJ = txtnewvalueJ.Text.ToString();

                        if (oldvalue != newvalue && oldvalueJ != newvalueJ)
                        {
                            grdView.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            grdView.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that Grid has the following fields and rows values.

- [lblJurisdiction] - [txtLicenseNumber] - [IssueDate]
- [Abc]          - [123]           - [12/12/2015]
- [Abc]          - [123]           - [12/12/2015]
- [Abc]          - [123]           - [12/12/2015]
- [def]          - [123]           - [12/12/2015]
- [def]          - [123]           - [12/12/2015]
- [def]          - [123]           - [12/12/2015]

The values are duplicated in the grid view because of join operation at the time of data binding. Due to some requirement, I have to fetch only one.

Now I want to make only one of them visible like

- [Abc]          - [123]           - [12/12/2015]
- [def]          - [123]           - [12/12/2015]

The above code does not work. Please help !!!

Comment: Why would you not filter in the underlying collection that is Databound, using simple Linq, that would be much easier to achieve. I am assuming GridView is a DataTable

Comment: All you need a simple Linq Distinct with an `IEqualityComparer<DataRow>` to achieve the Task, Just 3-4 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop have problem. It should start with (i+1) to your row count. Your inner and other loop were fetching the same rows.

```
private void AvoidDuplicate()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtoldvalue = grdView.Rows[i].FindControl("txtLicenseNumber") as TextBox;
            string oldvalue = txtoldvalue.Text.ToString();

            Label txtoldvalueJ = grdView.Rows[i].FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label;
            string oldvalueJ = txtoldvalueJ.Text.ToString();

            if (oldvalue != "" || oldvalueJ !="")  
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j < grdView.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    TextBox txtnewvalue = grdView.Rows[j].FindControl("txtLicenseNumber") as TextBox;
                    string newvalue = txtnewvalue.Text.ToString();

                    Label txtnewvalueJ = grdView.Rows[j].FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label;
                    string newvalueJ = txtnewvalueJ.Text.ToString();

                        if (oldvalue != newvalue || oldvalueJ != newvalueJ)
                        {
                            grdView.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            grdView.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Better way to use **DefaultView**. Remove the duplicate rows from datatable(source of gridview) itself.

```
datatable = datatable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Col1ToCompare", "Col2ToCompare");
```

Comment: I am sorry the above code is retrieving only one of them.

Comment: Hmm. you need to change AND to OR for value and valueJ. Updated the answer.

Comment: We need to brake once we have the match. Try the code again.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a method to merge `GridView` rows that has similar values. Never mind. I am not going to edit or review your code. But sharing the one I used as follows:

```
private void AvoidDuplicates()
{
    int i = GridView1.Rows.Count - 2; //GridView row count
    while (i >= 0) //Iterates through a while loop to get row index
    {
        GridViewRow curRow = GridView1.Rows[i]; //Gets the current row
        GridViewRow preRow = GridView1.Rows[i + 1]; //Gets the previous row

        int j = 0;
        while (j < curRow.Cells.Count) //Inner loop to get the row values
        {
            /****Condition to check if it has duplicate rows - Starts****/
            if (curRow.Cells[j].Text == preRow.Cells[j].Text) //Matches the row values
            {
                if (preRow.Cells[j].RowSpan < 2)
                {
                    curRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = 2;
                    preRow.Cells[j].Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    curRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = preRow.Cells[j].RowSpan + 1;
                    preRow.Cells[j].Visible = false;
                }
            }
           /****Ccondition to check if it has duplicate rows - Ends****/
            j++;
        }
        i--;
    }
}
```

Finally put the above method in the page load and see the result. Hope helps.